# Connect two elements keeping responsive value

Tags: css, html

I am creating a simple real estate website and am currently creating the listing page. I would like a product very similar to this [here](http://wp.realia.byaviators.com/property-type/family-house/). I cannot gain ideas from the code because I am using the [skeleton framework](http://www.getskeleton.com). This is my [current progress and code](http://kjrealty.com.au/testenvironment/lease.html) or below.

The two elements; photo of property and body of text are apart (there's a gap in the middle). 

And also if you resize the browser the listing is not rendered as a vertical rectangle as it is supposed to.

**My raw questions are:** 
*1) How do I connect the image and the body text so there is no space inbetween?*

2) How do I make the body text and image the same width when the body text needs to collapse underneath the photo? (When resizing browser or on device)

**The HTML**

```
    <div class="five columns image">
  <a href="Properties/9-Walter-Street-Claremont/Walter-Street.html"><img src="Properties/9-Walter-Street-Claremont/Listing.jpg" alt="Listing"></a>
</div>
<div class="ten columns body-info">
  <h2><a href="Properties/9-Walter-Street-Claremont/Walter-Street.html">Walter Street <span>$2500/wk</span></a></h2>
  <h3>Claremont, 6010</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <div class="info">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/bedrooms.png"> 5</li>
      <li><img src="img/bathrooms.png"> 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
   .body-info  {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.image a img:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background-image: url("img/eye.png");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
.body-info h2 a {
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
    color: #428f9c;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.image {
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}
.body-info {
    margin-left: 280px;
}
.body-info h2 a:hover {
    color: #0b7587;
}
.body-info span {
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #444;
}
.body-info p {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.body-info ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.body-info ul li {
    color: #777;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you a little bit on the way, you could use the `@media` on CSS.

With that you can change the style when for example the screen is smaller than a specific width.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">img</div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    background: gray;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.image {
    width: 270px;
    height: 180px;
    background: lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
}
.info {
    background: lightsteelblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    .image, .info {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

So what the style does is when you have a fullscreen it shows `.image` and `.info` next to each other (using `display: inline-block;`.
When the screen gets resized and smaller than 600px, for both the divs the display property will change to `block`, making them appear under each other.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/eCHGy/)**

Referring to the example in your post, the only thing you need to do is to make or find a script that resizes your image when the screen gets smaller.

Hope this helps you.